# Using ST_DWithin to see duplicates

Tags: postgis

I tried it this way but I think using DWithin might be better for this situation. What would be the correct order to find duplicates which exist within 10km from each other?

```
SELECT n, ST_ClusterDBSCAN(geog::geometry, eps := .08, minpoints := 2) over () AS cid
from (
select *
from cities as t
inner join
    (select n dn
     from cities as t
     group by n
     having count(*) >= 2) dups 
  on dups.dn = t.n
order by t.n
) d
```

EDIT: I guess I would have to do something like this:

```
select * from (SELECT *
    from (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by t.n) as rownum
    from cities as t
    inner join
        (select n dn
         from cities as t
         group by n
         having count(*) = 2
        ) dups 
      on dups.dn = t.n
    order by t.n
    ) d
    where mod(rownum,2) = 0) even, 
    (SELECT *
    from (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by t.n) as rownum
    from cities as t
    inner join
        (select n dn
         from cities as t
         group by n
         having count(*) = 2
        ) dups 
      on dups.dn = t.n
    order by t.n
    ) d
    where mod(rownum,1) = 0
    ) odd
    where st_dwithin(even.geog,odd.geog,5000)
```

but this is confusing... maybe it's better to just to do DWithin first but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Please add more context to your question. You have tried `ST_ClusterDBSCAN` to find duplicates, correct? Show us the select `ST_DWITHIN` statement you would use. If you find a duplicate, which one do you want to keep, and which one should be deleted, or do you want to delete both of them?

Comment: I'd like to keep the one with the least null values and I'd like to copy the `i` column's value to the other row before deleting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is just to identify duplicate records in your data. Then you can use ST_dwithin function like this;

```
  SELECT col1
  FROM cities as c1 
      INNER JOIN cities c2
  ON ST_dWithin(geom,10000)
  WHERE c1.gid != c2.gid AND c1.col1 = c2.col2
```

i assumed your data is in projected coordinate system (Unit: meters) and has a unique gid column. The duplication is based on col1, it may be name or any other value which should be unique in 10km radius.

Comment: This works really well. If you then wanted to remove duplicates what would your next step be? I'm not used to seeing multiple records on a single row

Comment: oh.. I think I figured it out. I can just reference the other columns like c1 and c2 to do the other things that I need like choosing which one to delete etc